# Process Builder Outbound Message

Tags: apex, process-builder, workflowoutboundmessage, http

I know that we can not send a Outbound message using process builder,
However we can have a workaround to invoke an apex method which calls send the http callout as explained here:

https://codecracksblog.wordpress.com/2016/08/12/call-outbound-message-functionality-in-process-builder-workaround/

1. I would like to know is it a good thing to do?
2. What will be the difference between this callout and workflow outbound message?
3. Is Callout Limits, one of the considerations?
4. What about the headers in Workflow Outbound message?

Comment: I solved this issue creating a Custom object. I am adding in this custom object using Process Builder. There is a workflow for this custom object that is calling the Outbound message.

Comment: We can definitely call workflow for outbound message, I'm curious to know that we can completely dump workflow and use process builder even for Outbound message.

Comment: I believe you can use. However, outbound message has resend and so on that I am not sure if you have this feature thru a HTTP callout.

Answer (score 3):

I'll try to answer point-by-point

1. Is it a good thing to do? One advantage to the HTTP Callout is that you have a greater range of options for the payload... you could send a collection, or related records. Outbound Messages don't have that option.
2. One of the best features of the Outbound Message (in my opinion) is the automatic queueing feature. Salesforce will re-try sending Outbound Messages for 24 hours if it doesn't get a response.
3. Callout limits could come into consideration depending on how often the process is invoked, but I would be more concerned about the dreaded "pending operations" exception.
4. I don't think I have anything to offer regarding Outbound Message headers...

I'll offer a suggestions, maybe best of both worlds.

1. Create a checkbox field on your sObject called "SendOBMessage"
2. Create a workflow rule that fires when the field is true
3. Create 2 workflow actions, one that sets the checkbox back to false, and the other sends the outbound message.
4. Have your process set the "SendOBMessage" field to true. You will get an Outbound Message!